# Extract unique values from JSON array and process it using apache camel

Tags: json, arraylist, apache-camel

I have JSON array like below.

```
"ArrayList": [{
        "id": "1234",       
        "dateOfBirth": -7181,       
        "name": {
            "firstName": "Ram",
            "lastName": "Sharma",
        }
    }, {
        "id": "1234",       
        "dateOfBirth": -7181,       
        "name": {
            "firstName": "Ram",
            "lastName": "Sharma",
        }
    }, {
        "id": "9876",       
        "dateOfBirth": -5197,       
        "name": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Martin",
        }
    }, {
        "id": "4567",       
        "dateOfBirth": null,        
        "name": {
            "firstName": "Manchester",
            "lastName": "United",
        }
    }
]
```

is there any way to extract unique values from this array list with dateOfBirth is not null and process it using apache camel Spring XML flow.

the resulted value before processing like

```
"ArrayList": [{
        "id": "1234",       
        "dateOfBirth": -7181,       
        "name": {
            "firstName": "Ram",
            "lastName": "Sharma",
        }
    } {
        "id": "9876",       
        "dateOfBirth": -5197,       
        "name": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Martin",
        }
    }
]
```